# Python IF Else and For loop workflow

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to write a function that returns the number of prime numbers that exist up to and including a given number.

Initially this was my code:

```
def count_primes(num):

    prime = [2]
    x = 3

    if num < 2:
        return 0

    while x <= num:
        for y in prime:
            if x%y == 0:
                print('not prime')
                x+=2
                break
            else:
                prime.append(x)
                x += 2

    return len(prime)
```

How ever I realise this code will run forever because of the following line of code:

```
for y in prime:
    if x%y == 0:
        print('not prime')
        x+=2
        break
    else:
        prime.append(x)
        x += 2
```

Can anyone help to explain to me why will this end up with an infinite loop compared to the following code?

```
for y in prime:
    if x%y == 0:
        print('not prime')
        x+=2
        break
else:
    prime.append(x)
    x += 2
```

Comment: Indentation in python is very important, the `else:` in the final example is with the `for` not the `if`. An `else` block on a `for` loop is only run if the loop completes (i.e. does not `break`). So the logic is if you find that the number is divisible by a prime then `break` else you get to the end of the loop and the number must be prime. See: https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops

Comment: From what i understand from your explanation, if i were to put the else: statement in the if statement, the code will run continuously in the for loop correct?

Comment: You have the issue of modifying `prime` which iterating over it, which is not something you should be doing as it can have unexpected results (like not terminating).

Comment: So in my case, the code will always run because it kept on iterating over my prime list while adding x into it at the same time. So in general, it will keep on going because my prime is constantly being added in the if statement. If so then i think i got what you mean. Thanks!